# Non-orthornormal basis of a Hilbert space

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces

Suppose I have a (infinite-dimensional) Hilbert Space $H$ with a countable orthornormal basis $\{e_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$. By definition, every element $x\in H$ can be expressed as an infinite sum
$$
x=\sum_{n\geq 0} c_n e_n
$$
Suppose now I know that I have some other set of vectors $\mathcal{B}=\{f_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}}$ and that each $e_n$ can be expressed as a $finite$ linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{B}$, that is 
$$
e_n=\sum_{m\geq 0} a_{nm} f_m,\quad \forall n\geq 0
$$
with only finitely many $a_{nm}$ non-zero for a given $n$ and similarly I can express all $f_m$ as a finite linear combination of $e_n$:
$$
f_n=\sum_{m\geq 0} b_{nm} e_m,\quad \forall n\geq 0
$$
with only finitely many $b_{nm}$ non-zero for a given $n$.

**Question**: Can every element $x\in H$ be written as 
$$
x=\sum_{n\geq 0} k_n f_n\quad ?
$$
where each $|k_n|<\infty$ are some coefficients? I am simply asking about existence.

The progress I have made so far is that I can write $x$ as the following:
$$
x=\sum_{m}\sum_{n} c_m a_{mn_m}f_{n_m}
$$
To get a positive answer to the question I need to swap the sums, which is possible when 
the series converges absolutely. For the moment I cannot say anything about absolute convergence, 
but the series does converge to $x$. When else do I need for absolute convergence?

**Update:** In order to clarify certain details regarding the origin of this problem and some further constraints let me state the following.

Suppose I have an infinite-dimensional inner product space $V$, with (Hammel) bases $\mathcal{B_1}=\{e_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ and $\mathcal{B_2}=\{f_n\}_{n\geq 0}$. The $e_n$ are orthonormal with respect to the inner product but the $f_n$ are not (or rather need not be). I then construct the Hilbert spaces $H_1$ of all convergent linear combinations
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n e_n,\quad |a_n|<\infty
$$
and the Hilbert space $H_2$ of all convergent linear combinations 
$$
\sum_{n\geq 0} b_n f_n,\quad |b_n|<\infty
$$
My question then becomes: Is $H_1=H_2$?

Comment: I think your first sum must be finite as well, no?

Comment: @DaniloGregorin Why is that? By definition of an orthonormal basis every vector in $H$ can be expressed as an infinite sum with finite coefficients.

Comment: You are correct, I mistook it by an algebraic basis. I apologize

Comment: I think You need this series to be [unconditionally convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconditional_convergence), but I don't see so far if it necessarily is. Unconditional convergence is weaker than absolute convergence.

Comment: The sum $\sum_n$ is finite, no? So you can swap the sums.

Comment: @mechanodroid The sum over $n$ is finite for a given $m$, but since I have a sum over all $m$ as well the sum over $n$ is actually infinite. I will update the question to indicate this.

Comment: You can always swap a finite and an infinite sum. Namely

$$\sum_{m\ge0} \sum_{n \ge 0} c_ma_{mn} f_n = \lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{m=0}^M \sum_{n \ge 0} c_ma_{mn} f_n = \sum_{n \ge 0} \lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{m=0}^Mc_ma_{mn} f_n = \sum_{n\ge 0}\left(\sum_{m \ge 0}c_ma_{mn}\right)f_n.$$

Comment: @mechanodroid This looks correct at a first glance, but since the outer sum $\sum_{n\geq 0}$ is finite this would imply that every $x\in H$ can be expressed as a finite linear combination of elements in $\mathcal{B}=\{f_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ which cannot be, since there is no countable Hamel-basis for an infinite dimensional Hilbert space??

Comment: I have added further details.

Comment: @Okazaki So You definitely assume $V$ to be not complete, since otherwise it could have no countable Hamel-basis and then You consider the closures of two Hamel-bases and ask whether they are identical?

Comment: I think they should be both identical to the closure of $V$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no. Consider the space $(c_{00}, \|\cdot\|_2)$ of all finitely-supported sequences equipped with the $\ell^2$-norm.

Let $(e_n)_n$ be the canonical vectors in $c_{00}$ and let $f_n = e_n + e_1$.
Then $(e_n)_n$ is an orthonormal Hamel basis for $c_{00}$ and $(f_n)_n$ is a Hamel basis for $c_{00}$.

Now, the completion of $(c_{00}, \|\cdot\|_2)$ is the Hilbert space $\ell^2$.

The sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1ne_n$ is an element of $\ell^2$ but it cannot be written as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_nf_n$. Indeed, we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1ne_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_nf_n = \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n\right)e_1 + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \alpha_ne_n$$

It follows $\alpha_n = \frac1n$ for $n \ge 2$ but then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot!